# Getting Json Data in Soap webservice response

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, soap

I am using below code to get JSON in soap webservice response

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

try {
    SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

    //Adding values to request object
    request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

    //Adding Double value to request object
    PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();

    //Adding String value to request object
    request.addProperty("myParam1", "" + myParam1);
    request.addProperty("myParam2", "" + myParam2);
    SetEnvelope(url);

    try {             
        //SOAP calling webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Got Webservice response
        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        return Integer.parseInt(res);                 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
        //return 0;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    return -1;
    //return 2;
}
```

In response My Json Data was

```
({"result":"123456" })
```

Then I checked my Json online, it was wrong then i converted my JSON data

```
{"result":"123456" }
```

But in both the cases I am getting
Exception

```
 12-27 13:49:58.905: I/Webservice(2196):  unexpected type (position:TEXT [{"result":"" }]@1:16 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406d5c48)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace please. Also, what is `enveloppe` and what is `SoapObject`?

Comment: In stack trace, I am getting the exception of unexpected token and envelope in SoapSerializable, I have edited my Question.

Comment: I am little confused that whether I am getting correct response in json or the format is incorrect

Comment: 12-27 13:49:58.905: I/Webservice(2196):  unexpected type (position:TEXT [{"result":"" }]@1:16 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406d5c48)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are getting JSON so why are you trying to parse SOAP?
I found it complicated and almost impossible to deal with other then pure JSON responses.

I had my server side responding both in SOAP (for .NET) and JSON for (Android).

So here is what I use for getting the data from the remote service and to parse it (in this case as int).

```
//This method receives 2 parameters and return string - just example...
//I'm using HttpGet but there are also HttpPost objects
    public int getResults(String yourParameter1,String yourParameter2)


 {
        int results=0;
        Log.d("Webservice call:","Started");
        //Creating the get URL

        String url= "http://my.webservice.url/targetfile.aspx?parameter1="+yourParameter1+"&parameter2'"+yourParameter2;

        Log.d("URL:",url);
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        String tempresult="";
        Log.d("hc",hc.toString());
        Log.d("post",get.getURI().toString());
         try {
             HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
             Log.d("rp",rp.getEntity().toString());
             Log.d("rp2",rp.getStatusLine().toString());
             // Get hold of the response entity
                HttpEntity entity = rp.getEntity();
                // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
                // to worry about connection release
                tempresult=rp.toString();
                Log.d("tempresult",tempresult);
               if (entity != null) {

                    // A Simple JSON Response Read
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    tempresult= convertStreamToString(instream);
                    // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
                    instream.close();
                    Log.d("result",tempresult.toString());
                }
                //tempresults holding the JSON 
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tempresult);
             //getting the "results" value 
             results=Integer.parseInt(json.getString("result"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("error parsing JSON",e.toString());
                        }

         return results;
    }


//This method is to handle response
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Now, remember you'll need AsyncTask class to call such class especially if you want to get the results into the UI.